# ideal server configuration for long running php script

Tags: php, apache, nginx, fastcgi, long-polling

I am running a php longpolling script at localhost in apache server.. Xampp... Here at the backend , I have set the set_time_limit(0)... so that a while(true) loop can be executed effectively to run the longpolling uninterruptedly... If my website is accessed by 10,000 or more people in parallel , how can this affect my RAM usage.. I will use a dedicated server when putting the website online..But I want to know what kind of configurations will I have to make to execute this properly...

```
set_time_limit(0)

while(true){

//Longpolling query....

}else{
sleep(1);
continue;
}
```

So my questions are..

1. Is apache the right server for this?
2. How can this affect my server's memory usage and RAM usage?
3. What  correct configuration should I have to make [any memcached and power of RAM]
4. set_time_limit(0) is the best or anything more?
5. Will 1 dedicated server be enough or more?
6. How about Nginx and apache working together or Nginx and fastcgi?

Please show me some light here..

Comment: Your question is six questions, actually..all quite broad, too

Comment: I know.. if you can even answer 1 or 2 then it will be fine as well...

Comment: Apache: 16mb/user.. 10000 users = ~160Gb memory.

Comment: https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module - simple solution.